# Replacement of Apps in the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I have got a rare problem at the moment, hope I can get any help from here. Thanks in advance.

The thing is that my company has two apps, outsouced one (named A) and insourced one (B) both in the App Store and running normally. Of cource they are not identical but similar indeed.
There is a decision from the management that we are going to replace A with B, so that there is only one app in the app store instead of two.

Here is what I am thinking to archive this,
1. Pull off/Delete the app B from App store.
2. Create a new version of app A.
3. Recompile app B with A's bundle Id and etc., upload the build to itunes connect under the name of app A. (We have A's certificates and provisioning files)
4. Submit the build.

Has anyone done this ever before? Will apple reject this new app?
Any advice is welcome.
I appreciate all your help, and thanks for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep both of the app then you procedure is okay. You can give update to B (With A's source). It should work, though apple might reject if they find similarity with those two apps.

Almost similar problem happened to me once. One of our app is currently in AppStore, it was a generic app for one of our client. When we tried to release a new app just changing the images/logos and name then the AppStore rejected it. They said this app has limited feature. :P

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: I think if ZZk removes B first as he mentioned in step 1, Apple shouldn't have a problem as there will be only one app with those set of features.

Comment: @VarunSingh > Yes, thats why I mentioned "If you want to keep both app".. :)

Comment: I think you are right. The two apps look so different to each other, only one will be kept in the store, I do think it should be fine.